# x-axis and plot not synchronized

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to synchronize the timeline/x-axis with the plotted graph but it doesnt work properly. Anybody got an idea why the x-axis is running faster then the plot?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .graph .axis {
            stroke-width: 1;
        }

        .graph .axis .tick line {
            stroke: black;
        }

        .graph .axis .tick text {
            fill: black;
            font-size: 0.7em;
        }

        .graph .axis .domain {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
        }

        .graph .group {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
            stroke-width: 1.5;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="graph"></div>

        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var limit = 200,
            duration = 300,
            now = new Date(Date.now() - duration)

        var width = 500,
            height = 350

        var groups = {
            current: {
                value: 0,
                color: 'orange',
                data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
                    return 0
                })
            },
            target: {
                value: 0,
                color: 'green',
                data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
                    return 0
                })
            },
            output: {
                value: 0,
                color: 'grey',
                data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
                    return 0
                })
            }
        }

        var x = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([now - (limit - 2), now - duration])
            .range([0, width])

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 100])
            .range([height, 0])

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('basis')
            .x(function(d, i) {
                return x(now - (limit - 1 - i) * duration)
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return y(d)
            })

        // Container
        var svg = d3.select('.graph').append('svg')
            .attr('class', 'chart')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height + 50)

        // Bottom Axis
        var axis = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
            .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'))

        var paths = svg.append('g')

        // Painting
        for (var name in groups) {
            var group = groups[name]
            group.path = paths.append('path')
                .data([group.data])
                .attr('class', name + ' group')
                .style('stroke', group.color)
        }

        // Concrete Action
        function tick() {
        now = new Date()

            // Add new values
            for (var name in groups) {
                var group = groups[name]
                //group.data.push(group.value) // Real values arrive at irregular intervals
                group.data.push(Math.random() * 100)
                group.path.attr('d', line)
            }

            // Shift domain
            x.domain([now - (limit - 2) * duration, now - duration])

            // Slide x-axis left
            axis.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .ease('linear')
                .call(x.axis)

            // Slide paths left
            paths.attr('transform', null)
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .ease('linear')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(now - (limit - 1) * duration) + ')')
                .each('end', tick)

            // Remove oldest data point from each group
            for (var name in groups) {
                var group = groups[name]
                group.data.shift()
            }
        }

        tick()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Start example:

[image]

Shifted example after a view seconds:

[image]

It started at :15 and shifted more and more against :20

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the axis to move per second and show per 5 second labels, you can adjust how quickly the axis moves using `.ticks(d3.time.second, 5)` like this:

```
 var axis = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(x.axis =        d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').ticks(d3.time.second, 5))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/ejcnadp1/

Hope this helps!
Good luck.

Comment: the concrete problem is e.g. the start point of the plot is 12:08:30. if you let it run the start point is shifting to 12:08:31..31..32..33.. your fiddle has the same issue. :(

Comment: Hmm.. for how long? I've been watching it for more than three minutes and it is behaving correctly. (on Chrome and Firefox) Even after switching tabs, it is resuming as it should. The axis is shifting according to time. Could you maybe share a pic of the issue?

Comment: Do you mean that the starting point should be fixed and not move according to time?

Comment: no, i have added some pics.. it should be more understandable now :)

Comment: Oh now I see! Thanks!

Comment: I have managed to make it synchronize but I can't make it go smooth... https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/ejcnadp1/4/ This is really bugging me!

Comment: This http://codepen.io/atticweb/pen/GZKvgv and this helped https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/